# How to select from a select in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following data:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IH1XU.png

The first table is labeled "Offering" and the second is labeled "Instructor."

I am trying to sum the salaries of all the professors who do not have their instructor ID appear in the offering table.

What I did first was generate a table that has the data I need in it:

```
select distinct i.InstructorID, i.Salary
from Instructor i
where i.InstructorID NOT IN (select o.InstructorID from Offering o);
```

Which gives me the desired result here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJZDF.png

I then want to add these two salaries and have the result displayed in a single salary column.  I've tried code like:

```
$MySQL:> select sum(i.Salary) 
from Instructor i
where i.Salary in ( select distinct i.InstructorID, i.Salary
from Instructor i
where i.InstructorID NOT IN (select o.InstructorID from Offering o));
```

And get "SQLException: java.sql.SQLException: Operand should contain 1 co."  However, I am not sure how to contain the result from my previous query to one column.  The way I see it is if I was going to sum all of the salaries that were on the list and I just did a distinct Salary, it would only return three salaries rather than eight salaries, so it would be wrong to do that for my case too.

How would I add the two columns I have generated, and is there an easier way to complete my goal than the method I am using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use subqueries.  They are described by this [article](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just wrap this in a sub query:

```
select SUM(Salary)
from (
    select distinct i.InstructorID, i.Salary
    from Instructor i
    where i.InstructorID NOT IN (select o.InstructorID from Offering o)
)
```

This will work in SQL Server, I think it will work in MYSQL.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably join the two table and then do a group By.

Something like 
select sum(salary) from a, b where a.instructorid = b.instructorid and .....

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to do :

```
$MySQL:> select sum(i.Salary) 
from Instructor i
where i.Salary in ( select distinct i.Salary
from Instructor i
where i.InstructorID NOT IN (select o.InstructorID from Offering o));
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet InstructorID is a primary key in Instructor table and I think you don't need "distinct" in `select distinct InstructorID, Salary from Instructor`.

```
select sum(Salary)
from Instructor
where InstructorID not in (select InstructorID from Offering);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please test 3 different approaches and choose the best.

**NOT IN**

```
SELECT SUM(i.Salary)
FROM Instructor i
WHERE i.InstructorID NOT IN (select o.InstructorID from Offering o);
```

**LEFT JOIN with IS NULL**

```
SELECT SUM(i.Salary)
FROM Instructor i LEFT JOIN Offering o USING(InstructorID)
WHERE o.InstructorID IS NULL;
```

**NOT EXISTS**

```
SELECT SUM(i.Salary)
FROM Instructor i
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Offering o WHERE o.InstructorID = i.InstructorID);
```